# Why $x^{a\cdot b} \equiv x \pmod{n}$ where $b$ is the inverse of $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm currently studying the RSA algorithm and while I understand why if $b$ is the inverse of $a$ in $\Bbb Z_n $ then $ab  \equiv 1\pmod{n}$.  I don't quite understand why $x^{ab} \equiv x \pmod{n}$. Can I just replace $ab$ with $1$? A proof showing why this holds would be really helpful.

Comment: When $a\in\mathbb Z_n$, the expression $x^a\pmod n$ is not well-defined...

Comment: You misread, it should say $\,ab\equiv 1\pmod{\color{#c00}{\phi(n)}},$ and proofs are in the linked dupe. Post further question in comments here or there if anything remains unclear.

Comment: @BillDubuque I didn't misread, they mistyped. My comment is legitimate as a response to the question they asked.

Comment: @KentaS  *Now* you *have* misread.  My prior comment is to the OP, not you (if it was addressed  to you it would begin like this comment at-you)

Comment: @BillDubuque Sorry; my bad. I guess I misread your message.

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes,I did actually misread the proof...It's clear now,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Rather, we have
$$ x^{ab}\equiv x\pmod n$$
if
$$ ab\equiv 1\pmod{\phi(n)}\quad\text{and}\quad \gcd(x,n)=1.$$

Comment: You mean $\gcd(x,n)=1$, right?

Comment: @Mike Yes, off by one key :)

Comment: another connection for $a,b$ is when written in bsse $\phi(n)+1$ they have a product of digital roots that is congruent to $1\bmod\phi(n)$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment.This,and the post that was linked as the original question made things clear.I had actually misread the proof..This was bothering my mind for 2 days in a row.I need to be more focused.